# Ruby Open3.popen3 stdout pipe doesn't work when using a process monitor

Tags: ruby, process, stdout, pipe, monitor

I have noticed that when I run a ruby app using a process monitor, such as God or Bluepill, the part of the application that makes a `Open3.popen3() { |stdin, stdout, stderr| }` call doesn't work, specifically when reading from `stdout`. It works just fine when I run the ruby app directly using `ruby`.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Reading" from stdout? [Edit | Ah, I get what you mean]

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Can you get an `lsof` on the parent and child process and see that the three pipes are open and connected?